# Boldening text "Inside" a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea `#myarea` into which I'm typing text. I've typed this text.

> This is a sentence and only this word 
>   will end up being bolded

Now I have a button on the side, like a bold button. I want to select the letters I want bolded, click the button, and see those letters turn bold inside the textarea. It's similar to the standard functionality found in many editors, but I'm looking for something much simpler as I described here.

So is there a way to do this with jquery? I'm guessing it's a 2-part problem. I need to find the letters selected, then apply bold to them so it shows bold inside the textarea.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the only way to do this is with "contentEditable"; you can't style text in a `<textarea>` otherwise.

Comment: Does it have to be *inside* the textarea? Or could it be regular text in the `textarea` and bold in a preview pane (like SO's answer preview)?

Comment: Textarea's won't show html code formatting. `<strong>this</strong>` will show up as `<strong>this</strong>`. http://www.gosu.pl/steditor/ is a very small and simply wysiwyg editor that might fit your needs.

Comment: The only way I know if you really need a textarea is a ActiveXControl called DHTMLEDIT, but it requires MSIE and is not included anymore in Windows since Vista. But this control doesn't be simplier, it uses the same commands like  common WYSIWYG-editors(you may say this Control is the beginning of the WYSIWYG-editors known today).

Comment: You didn't ask for a solution that works with major-browsers, you asked for a solution that works with textarea's ;)

Comment: Well @sameold I'd like to give an example, but that's something I've never done - check @Alison's answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't mind using a div that has its ContentEditable property set to true then you can easily do this using:

```
document.execCommand('bold',null,false);
```

You can easily style this div to look and feel like a textarea.

See jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hqvDT/1/

Comment: And it is well supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable and http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I'll wait for more answers, maybe someone else has another suggestion, but this should work with some effort. I wonder what CKEditor uses because it has the features I'm describing exactly. I just don't know javascript well enough to read their js code and find out.

Comment: @Michaël Witrant, Thanks for the links.

Comment: @sameold: You'll need `contenteditable` or `designMode` (the latter is the same idea as `contenteditable` except that the entire document (typically a document inside an iframe) is editable). This answer will do what you want in all major browsers, although the markup it generates will vary. I *think* CKEditor does all its own DOM manipulation and doesn't use `execCommand()`, but that's a significant amount of work.