# Onclick event on list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6194511/2962505), but rather than using a button as he does in his jsfiddle, I'm trying to use list items:

http://jsfiddle.net/hqvDT/108/

It looks like it should work, but when I try to select some text and then press `B` (for bold), it doesn't actually bold the text.

What's wrong?

HTML:

```
<div id="myarea" contenteditable="true"></div>

<ul>
    <li onclick="MakeBold();">B</li>
    <li><i>I</i></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#myarea {
   border:1px solid #000;
   padding:5px; 
   height:150px;
   width:400px;
   overflow:scroll; 
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #999;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
}

ul li:hover {
    color: black;
}
```

JS:

```
function MakeBold() {
    document.execCommand('bold', null, false);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when an element other than a button is clicked, the selection in the textarea disappears.

On way to fix this is to use `onmousedown` instead of `onclick`, since the `mousedown` event is triggered before the text selection is lost.

```
<li onmousedown="MakeBold()">B</li>
```

Comment: This works, but then the problem is that the highlighted text doesn't stay highlighted. I guess I'll just have to use a button and style it accordingly.

Comment: You could also use some Javascript to save the selection and reselect the text when it's unselected, but I think styling the button how you want to is the easier route to take.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on a button does not de-select text selection.  Other elements when clicked will deselect the text.  Since the text is deselected before the click fires, the text will not be made bold.  You will either need to use a button or remember the selected text every time text is selected and deal with the saved selection.  I would really suggest sticking with a button.

Answer (score 0):

With mousedown and preventDefault.

HTML:

```
<div id="myarea" contenteditable="true">Mark a word of this paragraph and bold or italiced it</div>
    <ul>
        <li id="bolded">B</li>
        <li id="italiced"><i>I</i></li>
    </ul>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("bolded").addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  document.execCommand('bold', false, null)
})

document.getElementById("italiced").addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  document.execCommand('italic', false, null)
})
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/harivera/pen/wvodZOR